# Different view for different subdomains in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controllers

I am building a Rails application where I need to do a usability test of three different Views for the same application. My thought is to switch out the default view path depending on the subdomain.

For example, I'd like to be able to define the paths something like:

```
option1.mysite.com => views/option_1
option2.mysite.com => views/option_2
option3.mysite.com => views/option_3
```

I'd like to keep the Models and Controllers the same, but switch out the Views depending on the subdomain. What might be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

We do it something like this:

```
session[:site] = case request.subdomains.last 
        when "a" then "a"
        when "b" then "b"
        when "c" then "c"
end
```

That's part of a `set_site` method in our application controller. Every request checks to see if `session[:site]` is set; if not, it calls `set_site` to set it.

In your case, now you just need to introduce logic in your views to present things differently depending on the value of `session[:site]`, but it's even better if your actual view HTML is the same and the major difference is in the CSS. Then you just load different CSS files depending on the value of `session[:site]`.

Comment: Hi, this is helpful. Is there a method for setting the default view path?

Comment: Didn't really answer your question, did I. :) We opted not to do things that way, but you could look at [the documentation](http://railsapi.com/) for ActionController::Base.view_paths= and see if that does what you're after. It's certainly possible to tweak the paths the controller searches for views that way; I'm not sure if it's a per-request change, though.

Comment: Tried using view_paths and prepend_view_path but unfortunately it persists between requests, so the view gets set to last subdomain requested, which isn't what i want :-(